# Resolve all but a few domain names to a fixed IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, debian

On a Debian 10 machine, I would like all domain names to resolve to a fixed IP address, except for a handful that should still resolve to their original addresses.

I'm setting up a test environment for an app that does a lot of HTTPS requests to all sorts of domains (think search engine crawler). I have an HTTP server that can deliver canned answers which should receive all those requests, and I cannot instrument the code under test to use a proxy. However, the test machine should still be able to reach Debian's package servers for updates and the git server etc.

`/etc/hosts` does not seem to allow wildcards. Setting up `bind` looks like a lot of work, and I'm not sure if it covers my use case. Is there any package, or hook in the system I could use?

Comment: Look at the dnsmasq as most simple for your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dnsmasq for this, for instance to resolve all domains to the loopback, except for those to example.com, you'd place the following in `dnsmasq.conf`:

```
address=/#/127.0.0.1
server=/example.com/#
```

Comment: Sweet, pretty much an ideal solution :-)